# Java - How can I fill a Triangle and rotate it? (Polygon)

Tags: java, polygon, paintcomponent, graphics2d

So I got this which is a triangle, but how do I color it in? I am new to Java so bear with me. I also want later to copy it and paste it next to it and then rotate it on it's head. The figure I am trying to build is a [Kite](http://images.clipartpanda.com/kite-clipart-schoolfreeware_kite_coloring_book_colouring-1331px.png) (as you can see it's mainly build in different parts of traingles).

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    this.setBackground(Color.yellow);

    //this is where the triangle starts
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawPolygon(new int[] {40, 80, 120}, new int[] {100, 20, 100}, 3);
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `fillPolygon` will fill the shape with your color.

Comment: So what Do i need to code? Sorry I am a total noob :(

Comment: `g.drawPolygon` draws an outline. `g.fillPolygon` colors in that line. If you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) you could see that method.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is cast the graphics object g to a 2D grphics object.  For example:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

will allow you to use the tools included in the Graphics2D package, which you will need to import.  Then, you can create the triangle:

```
Polygon tri = new Polygon(new int[] {40, 20, 80}, new int[] {100, 20, 100}, 3);
```

Next, you need to rotate the triangle `THETA` degrees clockwise arround it's center and create it, filled:

```
g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(THETA), (140 / 3), (220 / 3));
g2.fill(tri);
```

This will create the triangle specified by coordinates {40, 20, 80} and {100, 20, 100}, rotated by `THETA` degrees.  The reason I specified the 2 extra parameters of rotate are because it would rotate around (0, 0) if they were not specified.  `140 / 3` is just the average of the x coordinates, and `220 / 3` is the average of the y coordinates.  If you know your geometry well, you will recognize this as the centroid of a triangle.  If you are rotating by the same  amount each time, you could just convert `THETA` to radians by hand.  There is, however, another way to do this.  You can rotate each point around the centroid of the triangle and then draw the polygon defined by these points.  To do this, it is easiest to derive a formula from the general rotation matrix.  Because this is Stack Overflow, I cannot very easily show you the derivation of the formula without LaTex support. In the end, the point `(x, y)` can be rotated around the center of the triangle `(xc, yc)` , by `THETA` degrees. using the formula `rX = ((x - xc) * cos(THETA)) - ((y - yc) * sin(THETA) + xc` to get the x coordinate of the rotated point, and `rY = ((x - xc) * sin(THETA)) + ((y - yc) * cos(THETA)) + yc`.  I trust that you can adapt this to java, but if you need help, tell me.  Remember, `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` take their parameter in radians, not degrees.  You will also need to round it, because the `Math.toRadians()` will not return an exact value, so most values supplied to `Math.cos()` or `Math.sin()` will evaluate to 0.